# datanucleus EntityManager merge is inserting new row instead of update

Tags: jpa, merge, datanucleus

CustomerSurvey.java

```
 public class CustomerSurvey
    implements Serializable
 {

/**
 * 
 */
private static final   long  serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "CUSTOMER_SURVEY_SEQUENCE") @Column(name = "SURVEYID", nullable = false) private String surveyId;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL) @JoinColumn(name = "CUSTNO", referencedColumnName = "CustNO") private Customer               customer;
@Column(name = "AVGRATINGS") private double                                                                                                                 avgRatings;

@Column(name = "COMMENTS") private String                                                                                                                   comments;

@Column(name = "SENTON") private Date                                                                                                                       sentOn;

@Column(name = "RESPONDEDON") private Date                                                                                                                  respondedOn;

@Column(name = "RESPONDED") int                                                                                                                             responded;
@Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customerSurvey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL) private Set<SurveyResponse>                              responses;

@XmlTransient @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.DETACH) @JoinColumn(name = "SRNO") private ServiceRequest                             serviceRequest;

@Column(name = "ATTACHMENT") @Lob @Basic(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) private byte[]                                                                            attachment;
--- getters and setters---

 public int hashCode()
     {
    return new HashCodeBuilder(17,31)
    .append(this.surveyId)
 //        .append(this.avgRatings)
 //        .append(this.getResponded())
    .toHashCode();

}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj)
{

    return new EqualsBuilder().
            append("SurveyId",this.surveyId)
//                .append("responded", this.getResponded())
//                .append("AvgRatings", this.getAvgRatings())
            .isEquals();
}
```

Persistence Code: 
     public void submitSurveyResponse(List surveys)
            throws WorkServiceException
    {

```
    if ( this.entityManagerFactory == null )
    {
        this.entityManagerFactory = this.getEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    EntityManager em = this.entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

    for (CustomerSurvey survey : surveys)
    {
        tx.begin();
        survey.setRespondedOn(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        survey.setResponded(BooleanResponse.YES.getCode());
        survey.setCustomer(em.find(Customer.class, survey.getCustomer().getCustNo().trim()));
        survey.setComments("Survey Response submitted");
        for (SurveyResponse response : survey.getResponses())
        {
            response.setQuestionair(em.find(Questionair.class, response.getQuestionair().getqNo()));
        }

        CustomerSurvey cs = em.find(CustomerSurvey.class, survey.getSurveyId());
        System.out.println(survey.equals(cs));
        Query query1 = em.createQuery("SELECT  from CustomerSurvey customerSurvey where customerSurvey.surveyId = :id")
                .setParameter("id", survey.getSurveyId());
        CustomerSurvey dbSurvey = (CustomerSurvey) query1.getResultList().get(0);
        System.out.println(":" + survey.equals(dbSurvey));

        if(survey.getServiceRequest() == null) {
            cs = em.find(CustomerSurvey.class, survey.getSurveyId());
            survey.setServiceRequest(cs.getServiceRequest());
        }
        CustomerSurvey mSurvey = em.merge(survey);

        String surveyId = mSurvey.getSurveyId();
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("surveyResponse.getAverageRatings");
        logger.trace(query.toString());
        query.setParameter("surveyId", surveyId);
        logger.trace(query.toString());

        Double avgRating = (Double) query.getSingleResult();
        if ( avgRating == null )
        {
            avgRating = new Double(0);
        }
        BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(avgRating);
        bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
        avgRating = bd.doubleValue();
        mSurvey.setAvgRatings(avgRating);
        em.flush();
        tx.commit();
   }
    em.clear();
    em.close();
}
```

It does not update , instead it inserts new row.
After using hashcode builder and equals builder I get false for folloing check: 
    The test for System.out.println(":" + survey.equals(dbSurvey)); gives false
    The test for             System.out.println(survey.equals(cs));
above gives false.

please advice

Comment: and the object is in what state when passed to "merge"? kind of crucial to what merge does. NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(obj) tells you

Comment: Also when I checked the state : I see Obj State: transient. I m making call using remote client (REST Call). When I make the same call from inside the container I see the state as detached. Thank you for leading me to find its state... Any suggetion on how to handle this gap?

Comment: I have edited my Question... I m using hashcode builder and equal builder, where the object comparison is returning false now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"transient" and "detached" are different states and will have different behaviour in *merge()* as per the JPA spec. transient will create a new object. detached with update an existing. Either obtain a detached object before modifying it, or read the section "Detachment" on http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_3_2/jpa/object_lifecycle.html

Comment: this helps to take care of transient object with key. The setting datanucleus.allowAttachOfTransient = true is done at the entity manager factory (persistenct) level. It is also impacting those object that are truely transient (with key is null, the entity yet to be created in db). and it tries to merge those objects too. What if I m only looking for the merge if transient + has an existing key? for now I used : CustomerSurvey refSurvey = em.find(CustomerSurvey.class, survey.getSurveyId()); if ( (NucleusJPAHelper.getObjectState(survey).equals("transient")) && (refSurvey != null) ) { ...

Comment: The description of that persistence property is very clear, and obviously any transient object without id will be persisted when calling merge() not attached and indeed all of our tests demonstrate that very fact, and that answers the question that you posted